# JSON Docusign Inline mulitpule Documents

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have my Json working for single document and transforms the PDF fields,  but when I try to add second document. I Get JSON Parse error.

This works

```
"document": {
"documentId": "1",
"name": "Test Contract With Fields.pdf",
"transformPdfFields": "true",
"documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'"
    }
```

this also works but doesn't transforms the PDFFields.

```
 "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
              "documentId": "1",
              "name": "test",
              "transformPdfFields": "true"
            },
            {
              "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
              "documentId": "2",
              "name": "test 2",
              "order": "2"
            }
          ],
```

Adding Square [] and second document breaks. Tried making `Documents`

```
    "document": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Test Contract With Fields.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "true",
        "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'"
    },
    {

        "documentId": "2",
        "name": "Test Contract With Fields 2.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "true",
        "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'"

    }]
```

**Update: Complete JSON
Looking to add a second **document****

```
{
    "emailBlurb": "Test Blurb",
    "emailSubject": "Test subject",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1","documents": [
              {
                "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'",
"documentId": "2",
              "name": "Not working", "order": "2"
            }
          ],

                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "*******",
                                "name": "********e",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "smsAuthentication": {
                                "senderProvidedNumbers": ["******"]
                                },
                                "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                                "requireIdLookup": "true",
                                "clientUserId": "1001",
                                "defaultRecipient": "true",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "pageNumber": "1",
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "tabLabel": "text 1",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "fullNameTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "pageNumber": "1",
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "xPosition": "20",
                                            "yPosition": "20",
                                            "height": "10",
                                            "width": "20",
                                            "tabLabel": "Text 2",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "pageNumber": "1",
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "xPosition": "20",
                                            "yPosition": "30",
                                            "height": "10",
                                            "width": "20",
                                            "tabLabel": "text 3",
                                            "recipientId": "1"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": "1",
                "name": "Working",
                "transformPdfFields": "true",
                "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'"
            }       }
    ]
```

Comment: can you put the entire JSON, not just a snippet? you can validate JSON here - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Added full JSON only looking to add a second document.

Comment: missing closing end } at tne end, no? please see JSON validator

Comment: The JSON does load in DocuSign. Just cant get a second document.

Comment: your question said "I Get JSON Parse error."
Do you not get a JSON parse error? if so - what error do you get?

Comment: BTW, this JSON only has one document

Comment: How do I add the second document.  If [] and second document to document node. I get docusign json error even with valid json.

Comment: in JSON [] denotes an array. You closed the array after the first document so you couldn't add another one. You need to add a comma and then add your second document. Ensure you have valid JSON and it will work ok.

Comment: instead of:
               }
            ],
            "document": {
do:
               },
            "document": {

Comment: I added valid JSON in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 "models" for constructing envelopes. I recommend using composite templates in the intended way, where you manage each document contribution to the envelope by enclosing within separate *compositeTemplate* elements.  I reworked your JSON like this:

```
{
  "emailBlurb": "Test Blurb",
  "emailSubject": "Test subject",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [{
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Working",
        "transformPdfFields": "true",
        "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [{
            "email": "*******",
            "name": "********e",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "smsAuthentication": {
              "senderProvidedNumbers": ["******"]
            },
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",
            "clientUserId": "1001",
            "defaultRecipient": "true"
          }]
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'",
        "documentId": "2",
        "name": "Not working",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [{
            "email": "*******",
            "name": "********e",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "smsAuthentication": {
              "senderProvidedNumbers": ["******"]
            },
            "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",
            "clientUserId": "1001",
            "defaultRecipient": "true"
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

In this fashion, any number of additional documents you wish to add would simply be another *compositeTemplate* element added to the array. This works for additional documents regardless of whether you wish to transform PDF fields, documents sourced from DocuSign templates, or any additional document for which you want to apply a template to overlay.

Note that the use of *compositeTemplateId* is only needed to relate multipart form attachments, which is a cleaner way to handle your documents rather than base64 encoding them in *documentBase64* elements.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed JSON:

```
    {
        "emailBlurb": "Test Blurb",
        "emailSubject": "Test subject",
        "status": "sent",
        "compositeTemplates": [
            {
                "compositeTemplateId": "1",
                "inlineTemplates": [
                    {
                        "sequence": "1","documents": [
                  {
                    "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'",
    "documentId": "2",
                  "name": "Not working", "order": "2"
                }
              ],

                        "recipients": {
                            "signers": [
                                {
                                    "email": "*******",
                                    "name": "********e",
                                    "recipientId": "1",
                                    "smsAuthentication": {
                                    "senderProvidedNumbers": ["******"]
                                    },
                                    "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                                    "requireIdLookup": "true",
                                    "clientUserId": "1001",
                                    "defaultRecipient": "true",
                                    "tabs": {
                                        "signHereTabs": [
                                            {
                                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                                "documentId": "1",
                                                "tabLabel": "text 1",
                                                "recipientId": "1"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "fullNameTabs": [
                                            {
                                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                                "documentId": "1",
                                                "xPosition": "20",
                                                "yPosition": "20",
                                                "height": "10",
                                                "width": "20",
                                                "tabLabel": "Text 2",
                                                "recipientId": "1"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "dateSignedTabs": [
                                            {
                                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                                "documentId": "1",
                                                "xPosition": "20",
                                                "yPosition": "30",
                                                "height": "10",
                                                "width": "20",
                                                "tabLabel": "text 3",
                                                "recipientId": "1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "name": "Working",
                    "transformPdfFields": "true",
                    "documentBase64": "'.$documentHashpdf.'"
                    }       
               ]}
        ]
    }
```